# SQL: How can I merge multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql-server, pivot

This is my first post in this very helpful blog.
In my attendance system, I’ve different section and every section has 3 or 4 shifts.  Like A Shift B Shift and C Shift.
I have an SQL query. Which output is multiple row for every shift.

```
SELECT          
            sc.SectName,sns.ShiftName,
            dbo.fn_ReceptiveEmployee_SectionWise(sc.Sect_Number) as SetupForWorker,
            dbo.fn_AsperRegister_SectionWise(sc.Sect_Number, prd.Shift_Number,'01 jan 2017') as HandsInRegister,
            isnull(dbo.fn_Daily_Present_Days_SectWise(sc.Sect_Number, prd.Shift_Number,'01 jan 2017'),0) as EmpTotalPresent,
            isnull(dbo.fn_Daily_Late_Days_SectWise(sc.Sect_Number,prd.Shift_Number,'01 jan 2017'),0) as EmpTotalLate,       
            isnull(dbo.fn_Daily_Absent_Days_SectWise(sc.Sect_Number,prd.Shift_Number,'01 jan 2017'),0) as EmpTotalAbsent,
            isnull(dbo.fn_Daily_WH_Days_SectWise(sc.Sect_Number,prd.Shift_Number,'01 jan 2017'),0) as EmpTotalWHDay,        
            isnull(dbo.fn_Daily_Leave_Total_SectWise(sc.Sect_Number,prd.Shift_Number,'01 jan 2017'),0) as EmpTotalLeaveDay
        
        FROM    dbo.tblEmployee emp INNER JOIN
                dbo.tblProcessed_Data prd ON emp.Emp_Number = prd.Emp_Number INNER JOIN
                dbo.tblSection sc ON emp.Sect_Number = sc.Sect_Number INNER JOIN
                dbo.tblDesignation dsg ON emp.Desig_Number = dsg.Desig_Number INNER JOIN
                dbo.tblDepartment dpt ON sc.Dept_Number = dpt.Dept_Number INNER JOIN
                dbo.tblBranch br ON dpt.Branch_Number = br.Branch_Number INNER JOIN
                dbo.tblCompany cmp ON dpt.Comp_Number = cmp.Comp_Number INNER JOIN 
                dbo.tbl_ShiftNameSettings sns ON sns.Shift_Number= prd.Shift_Number

        Where   emp.EmpED = 1 
                and br.Branch_Number = 2    
                and prd.PunchDate = convert(varchar,'01 jan 2017',12)
                and cmp.Comp_Number = 1
                --and dbo.tblProcessed_Data.Shift_Number = 1
                
        group by prd.Shift_Number, sns.ShiftName,sc.Sect_Number,sc.SectName
```

But I want every shift will be marge in one row for every section.

[image: Result]

It should be....

[image: Result in One Row]

Please help me..
Thank You.

Comment: Do you only need the result to be printed horizontally, or do you plan to use the result on other query? What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Hello! I need the query result horizontally in one row as my last picture, which is now generated in three different rows for each shift. Thank You.